# Why can you say “not only will I” but not “not only I will”?

Tags: word-order, negation, subject-verb-inversion, adverb-position, focusing-adverbs

Given:

1. Not only **will I** be skipping the breakfast, but the lunch too.
2. Not only ❌**I will** be skipping the breakfast, but the lunch too.

Why does sentence (2) sound so terribly wrong? Why is sentence (1) grammatical and sentence (2) ungrammatical? Please explain why this strange ordering restriction of subject and auxiliary verb applies here.

In contrast, the ordering restriction in (1)/(2) does not seem to apply to any of these versions, where the verb is fine to follow the subject once you’ve moved *not only* around a bit in the sentence:

3. **I will** not only be skipping the breakfast, but the lunch too.
4. **I will** be skipping not only the breakfast, but the lunch too.
5. **I will** be not only skipping the breakfast, but the lunch too.

If you switched *I will* to *Will I* in any of (3), (4), or (5), the result would now not be grammatical the way it is in (1).

Why makes (1) so special?

Comment: please see; [inversion of sentence structure with negatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=sentence+inversion+with+negatives)

Comment: [Assorted related questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3a%22not%20only%22).

Comment: Interesting. It's conceivable that (2) might appear in something like "In that case, not only I will be skipping breakfast, but everyone else will too." That is, the contrast/link is *I–everyone* rather than *breakfast–lunch.*

Comment: Probably the intent is "skipping breakfast, but lunch, too." No articles. Unless the hotel had the breakfast in the lobby included, and the lunch there, too. Then it's the free meals.

Answer (score 5):

When a negative phrase like *not only* is moved from its usual position after the first auxiliary verb (or before the main verb if there's no auxiliary) to the beginning of the sentence (usually to emphasize it), then the first auxiliary verb  changes places with the subject. Thus

- *They have **not only** won, they have won decisively.*
- **Not only **they have** won, they have won decisively*
- *Not only **have they** won, they have won decisively.*

As usual, if there is no auxiliary verb to invert, *Do*-support provides one.

- *They **not only** won, they won decisively.*
- **Not only **they won**, they won decisively*
- *Not only **did they win**, they won decisively.*

Note that the past tense on *won* is switched to the auxiliary *did*, since the first auxiliary verb in a tensed clause carries the tense marker, if there is one.
The process is called Subject-Auxiliary Inversion, and it occurs in other constructions, like questions. We don't say **Won they?* any more; we say *Did they win?*

Comment: Would you care to comment on something like "Not only they won; my team did too"? That is, it's the element immediately following *not only* which is contrasted — "*they/us*"; "just *won/won decisively.*"

Comment: It wouldn't fly in speech; the contrastive pronoun would hafta be stressed very heavily, and pronouns are not really strong enough for that kind of stress. In writing, of course, it's hopeless because you can't show the stress.